# Encompassing jQuery Accordion list item with <a> tag

Tags: html, css

On my plain `HTML` page there is a Horizontal Accordion based on jQuery.

In the accordion the expanding images is declared in a `class="bg1"`.

The href= should cover the whole `<li class="bg1">` image not only a single textline (see my example).
How can I define the `<a href=` to cover the whole bg1 image?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <li class="bg1">
        <div class="heading">Jazzband</div>
        <div class="bgDescription"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <h2>Jazzband</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                nulla pariatur.</p>
            <a href="http://www.my_website.com">more &rarr;</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    ...........
```

CSS:

```
ul.accordion{
    list-style:none;   
    position:absolute;
    right:80px;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
ul.accordion li{
    float:right;
    width:115px;
    height:480px;
    display:block;
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
}
ul.accordion li.bg1{
    background-image:url(../imgs/bg1_img.jpg);
}
```

The JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#accordion > li').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'600px'},500);        // statt 480px
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Change it from `<li class="bg1">` to `<li><a href="whatever"><div class="bg1">`, and make the `bg1` class apply to a div instead of a list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchor tag needs to be the first thing inside the `<li>` tag; the tag itself is required to provide the Accordion functionality. However, you should be able to wrap everything in a `<div>`, wrap that in your link, and stick that into the `<li>` tag.

Try changing it from `<li class="bg1">` to `<li><a href="http://www.my_website.com"><div class="bg1">`, and make the `bg1` class apply to a div instead of a list item.

```
<ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.my_website.com/">
            <div class="bg1"> <!-- The div becomes the link and the background -->
                <div class="heading">Jazzband</div>
                <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2>Jazzband</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...............
</ul>
```

You might have to play with CSS a bit to make it work correctly, but it should provide you the functionality you desire (ie. the whole background of the accordion-ed list item serves as the hyperlink).

Comment: Thats close - will try to fix the CSS:
'code' ul.accordion li.bg1{
    background-image:url(../imgs/bg1_img.jpg);
}     is not working anymore.

Comment: Yeah; that won't work until you change it from `li.bg1` to `div.bg1`, since the `li` part specifies a list item, when in actuality you're assigning the background to a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag needs to surround the li tag.

```
<a href="http://www.my_website.com">
     <li class="bg1">
            <div class="heading">Jazzband</div>
            <div class="bgDescription"></div>
            <div class="description">
                <h2>Jazzband</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla pariatur.</p>

            </div>
        </li>
</a>
```

Comment: If i do this - the jQuery accordion is not fading (expanding) anymore. 
The jQuery function: $('#accordion > li').hover(
 function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'600px'},500);        // statt 480px
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    },

Comment: with this Javascript is not anymore functioning!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole li in the  like this

```
 <ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <a href="http://www.my_website.com">
        <li class="bg1">
            <div class="heading">Jazzband</div>
            <div class="bgDescription"></div>
            <div class="description">
                <h2>Jazzband</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                    reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla pariatur.</p>

            </div>
        </li>
      </a>
        ...........
```

Comment: If i do this - the jQuery accordion is not fading (expanding) anymore. 
The jQuery function: $('#accordion > li').hover(
 function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'600px'},500);        // statt 480px
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    },

Comment: Javascript is not anymore functioning with the li wrap around '<'a href=